# Why png image is not visible

Tags: node-editor

I have used the png image and added the nodes as seen below

[image]

After render i cant seen the "CE.png" image on the button

**After render**

[image]

Where are my node missing to view my image

Any suggestion or help.

[image]

Comment: You have the mix shader going into the Displacement of your material.  Are you trying to make it bump-mapped?  I would suggest using the Displace modifier instead.  Otherwise, just move the shader to Surface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect **Mix Shader** to **Surface** socket in **Material Output** node not to **Displacement**.

[image: Nodes]